# Unable to establish websocket connection on Weblogic 12.1.3 and 12.2.1.3. It fails with 404 not found error

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I could debug and find that TyrusWebsocketEngine is not upgrading the websocket request and Upgrade status is "NOT_AVAILABLE". I have used sock.js on client side and spring stomp on server side.